# How to get USB Serial number connected with the mac os 10.7.5

Tags: ios, cocoa, usbserial

I follow the below link.method(void getUSBStringDescriptor)
http://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number-osx/

method i have used is:

its working fine on mac 10.8.4 but not in 10.7.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is being returned?

Comment: method getUSBStringDescriptor gives me the serial number in string which i want but this code does not run on 10.7.5, works well on 10.8.4